# Creating values from a normal inverse gaussian (NIG) distribution

Tags: histogram, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I have a vector of empirical observations 'a' containing about 16000 values.

[empirical data](https://github.com/Maxim-ml/Data/blob/master/mydata.txt)

The empirical histogram looks like the following:
[image]

I'm trying to test, whether the normal inverse gaussian (NIG) fits the empirical data or not. First, I estimate the distribution parameters on the data:

`SP500NIG<-fit.NIGuv(a, silent = TRUE)`

Then I try to generate values from the NIG distribution with the parameters above. I do the following:

`library(fBasics)`

`SP_NIG_sim<-rnig(length(a),mu=SP500NIG@mu,delta=SP500NIG@sigma,alpha = SP500NIG@alpha.bar,beta=SP500NIG@gamma)`

And get the corresponding theoretical histogram, which doesn't look like the empirical one:

[image]

Where is the mistake in my code? How to generate values from the NIG distribution with the estimated parameters, which will more or less coincide with the empirical data?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for providing a link to your data. But your code is not runnable. I have found `fit.NIGuv()` in the `ghyp` package, but where does `rnig()` come from? Please ensure that all packages are loaded by including the `library()` call. Best to test your question in a new R console.

Comment: `rnig` function comes from `fBasics` package. I have added this information to the question.